# Example of a one point set in a metric space that is not closed

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I know that in any metric space, not all one point sets are closed, but I can't think why, or think of an example.

Comment: All one point sets are closed in a metric space. But sometimes they are also open.

Comment: Let $X$ be a metric space and $d$ the distance function on $X$.  We know that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$.  Now, we can show that $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open because for every point $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, $d(x,y)\not=0$, so if you consider the ball around $y$ of radius $d(x,y)$, then this ball doesn't contain $x$, so it is $X\setminus \{x\}$.  Since this works for every point of $X\setminus\{x\}$, $X\setminus\{x\}$ is open, and, hence, its complement, $\{x\}$ is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually that's not true. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $x \in X$. Now let $y \in X$ with $y \neq x$. Set $r = d(x,y)$. Then
$$B_{r/2}(y) \subset X \setminus \{x\},$$
so $X \setminus \{x\}$ is open, hence $\{x\}$ is closed.

As pointed out in the comments, it is possible for $\{x\}$ to be open. Suppose, for example that $d$ is the metric
$$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{if $x \neq y$}\\ 0 \hspace{1cm} \textrm{if $x = y$}\end{cases}$$ if $x \neq y$ and $0$ if $x = y$.
Then $d$ induces the discrete topology, so all sets are open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a metric space, and $x\in X$, if $Y=X-\{x\}$ is empty, it is open. If it is not empty, let $y\in Y,$ the open ball $B(y,d(x,y)/2)$ is contained in $Y$ we deduce that $Y$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

To see why all one point sets in a metric space are closed considered the complement of the the one point set. Let's call this $S$ and the one point will be $x$, given any $p\in S$ take the open ball centred at p with radius equal to the distance between p and x. Clearly this is contained in $S$ and thus $S$ is open. Since it is open it's complement must be closed which means that the one point set is closed.